# Create link of empty box

Tags: beamer, hyperref, boxes, minipage

I make my first attempt on a beamer template. I created a simple graphic with my company logo and some fields as header (background for title). Now I would like to use the logo as `home button`. In other words once I click it, it goes to the `toc`.

To I'd like to create an empty box overlaying the logo, since I don't want to link the entire graphic or split it up into two graphics.

Within my style file I set the graphic the folling way:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
     \ifnum\c@framenumber=0%
          \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{/u1/Berichte2/theme/title.pdf}
     \else%
          \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{/u1/Berichte2/theme/header.pdf}
      \fi}
```

Now I tried to put `minipage, mbox, makebox, framebox, ...` into the Background environment which didn't throw me any errors but didn't do draw anything eather. If I put it somewhere else it complains about missing `\begin{document}`

Any help how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not having access to your images, about how big are they with respect to the screen?  Where do you want the links placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates an invisible link box in the center of the frame.  You can tell where it is when the cursor changes.  (Not on the image here, which is only a .png copy.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \rlap{\hspace{0.25\paperwidth}\hyperlink{test}{\rule[0.25\paperheight]{0.5\paperwidth}{0.5\paperheight}}}%
     \ifnum\c@framenumber=0%
       \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
     \else%
       \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}%
     \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
test frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\hypertarget{test}{test target}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer frame]

This one puts a white visible link box over the image.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
     \ifnum\c@framenumber=0%
       \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
     \else%
       \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}%
     \fi
     \hspace{-0.75\paperwidth}\hyperlink{test}{\color{white}\rule[0.25\paperheight]{0.5\paperwidth}{0.5\paperheight}}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
test frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\hypertarget{test}{test target}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: link on top]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, this works like a charm. Now I only have to find a way to make the box white.

Comment: You wanted it on top?  No problem.

Comment: I didn't articulate that good enough, the thing is that my background image is semi-transparent. So if I now underlay it with something black I can see it. What I did is exchange transparent with white and all done. But thank you for adjusting your answer for me.